# Постоянное соединение на обычном хостинге

Tags: ajax, php, long-poll, mysql

Понадобилось сделать простенькое расширения для хрома, там мне нужно чтобы туда приходили данные мгновенно по инициативе сервера. Я много читал про это, про comet, webSockets и т.д. Но все это требует vps или vds. Для моей задачи, покупать сервак глупо, так как я пока что не планирую на этом что-то зарабатывать и мне жалко платить за сервер, пусть и vps стоят не очень дорого. А простой веб хостинг для меня почти бесплатен.
Я стал думать как обойтись без этих инструментов и в голове у меня только один вариант, это постоянный опрос бд аяксом на новые события, но так, как мне нужно минимальное время отдачи и вполне возможно, что пользователей у меня будет достаточно не мало (даже если 1к - уже в таком случае много, а у меня думаю будет больше) и расширение будет работать всегда, когда открыт браузер, то я боюсь высоченной нагрузки (допустим если опрашивать раз в 1 секунду, хотя для меня это уже много).

Сами по себе запросы будут простые и таблица, опрашиваемая тоже достаточно маленькая, но из-за большого количества я боюсь не справится сервер.

Вот скажите, я верно опасаюсь? Или же не такая уж и сильная нагрузка будет? Все-таки малюсенкий запрос, на проверку из малюсенькой таблицы (выбераем по определенному ИД и наличию новых событий, если есть - достаем и отправляем юзеру).
Подскажите, как можно решить этот вопрос, не прибегая к покупке сервера?

Comment: что значит "обычный хостинг" ?

Comment: ну простейший веб-хостинг

Comment: я думаю под "обычным" имеется в виду поддержка mysql, php?  но на которых нет vps или vds. Обычный хостинг по минимальной цене?

Comment: именно так

Comment: по поиску free vps [например](http://onenv.ru/free-vps)

Comment: Тоннель SSH на хостинг кинуть можно? А postgres поставить?

Answer (score 1):

Опасаетесь верно. Нельзя недооценивать пользователей, вам может показаться, что у вас их 50 в день и пользуются они вашим порталом по часу в день. Однако, если вы раз в секунду выводите какую-то информацию, вероятно она носит событийный характер и пользователи ее могут ждать. На практике все это выливается в десяток вкладок с вашим порталом, оставленных на ночь. Т.е. одни человек случайно или намеренно может создать нагрузку, с которой ваш сервис просто не справится.

Более того, вы почти не можете контролировать AJAX, допустим вы определили, что частота в одну секунду слишком велика и хотите ее снизить до одного раза в 10 секунд. Но уже поздно, у пользователей уже открыты десяток вкладок (половину которых из-за обилия уже открытых вкладок они даже не видят) и они долбят раз в секунду, так как частота опроса задана на стороне JS.

В общем какое-то время все будет работать, однако, если проблемы начнутся, решить их будет крайне сложно.

Comment: А нельзя ли включать скрипт, только если вкладка в фокусе?